# What class should I use instead of the deprecated AmazonCloudFrontClient?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I am trying to invalidate items in cloud front. I fount that the class http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/cloudfront_2012_03_15/AmazonCloudFrontClient.html is deprecated.

What class should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a class with the same name in another package which is not `@Deprecated`:

[Docs for `com.amazonaws.services.cloudfront.AmazonCloudFrontClient`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/cloudfront/AmazonCloudFrontClient.html)

The deprecated class is in the namespace `com.amazonaws.services.cloudfront_2012_03_15.AmazonCloudFrontClient`.

Answer (score 0):

I realized my IDE was importing from the wrong package.

Use this:

```
import com.amazonaws.services.cloudfront.AmazonCloudFrontClient;
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/cloudfront/AmazonCloudFrontClient.html#createInvalidation(com.amazonaws.services.cloudfront.model.CreateInvalidationRequest